# jQuery not keeping div hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Checks to see if div has been closed
if(sessionStorage.getItem("hide") != true) {
    $('#domainReco').show();
} else {
    $('#domainReco').css("display", "none");
}
$("#boxclose").click(function(){
    $("#domainReco").fadeOut();
    sessionStorage.setItem("hide", true);
    return false;
});  
});
</script>
echo '<div id="domainReco">';
    echo '<a class="boxclose" id="boxclose"></a>';
    echo '<h2>You are in the EU store</h2>';
    echo '<p>Want to visit the <a href="">US store</a> instead?<p>';
echo '</div>';
```

When clicking the link, the div does hide but after navigationg to another page, the div is there again. I have searched, but can't seem to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: jquery  is client side so when page reloads it resets to original state

Comment: You will need to use cookies

Comment: when using jquery use it to the fullest, you can replace this `$('#domainReco').css("display", "none");` with  `$('#domainReco').hide()`

Comment: Well that is the normal behavior. Scripts are executed per page they don't preserve state unless it's transferred with the appropriate tools.

Comment: Oh you're using storage, my bad

Comment: @DoYouEvenHTML is using sessionStorage

Answer (score 3):

You are making wrong comparison. Variables are not saved as bool, they are saved as string. it should be:

```
 sessionStorage.getItem("hide") !="true"//not (sessionStorage.getItem("hide") !=true)
```

Comment: This is correct, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp shows that the values are stored as strings